# Cannot see AD after migrating from 2008 to 2012R2 domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, migration

A friend of mine helped me migrate from a Server 2008 AD to a 2012 R2.  He transferred control from the old machine to the new, deactivated the old and then upgraded the new to be a pure 2012R2 domain.  I noticed the following day that my Windows 10 machines cannot authentic against the machine.  A Windows 8.1 machine is not able to automatically run the login scripts any more.

When I try to add a new 2012R2 server to the domain by entering the IP address of the AD, I get the error:

```
An active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for the domain "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" could not be connected
```

When I type in the domain name I get the same thing where the IP is changed for the domain name.  Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check DNS configuration: *probably you clients can't find domain*.

If DNS role present on 2012 R2 DC (most likely so) try configure it as DNS server for domain clients.

**P.S.**

> When I try to add a new 2012R2 server to the domain by entering the IP
>   address of the AD, I get the error...

In this field you can enter **only domain name** but does not IP address.

Comment: It was the DNS configuration.  I am using the DHCP server on the crappy router and for reasons beyond my understanding I have changed the IP address for the first DNS server on the unit, but no matter what I try, the unit still uses the old DNS settings.  For now I simply hard coded the DNS on the client machine, when everyone else isn't using the network I will reconfigure it to use another DHCP Server.